# Website is scrolling horizontally to the right when there is no visible content there

Tags: html, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I've recently launched a website and seem to be having a problem with a static page I have created. It isn't a major issue but it is really bugging me!

The website in question is: http://gadgetmill.co.uk/

Basically I have hidden the horizontal scroll bar via CSS but want to get to the root of the problem and solve it rather than cover it up. The problem is that the website keeps wanting to scroll horizontally when there is no visible content to the right anyway.

I'm assuming it is the footer that is triggering this but would be very grateful if someone could tell me what to change to fix this?

Thanks a lot, and a happy new year!

Comment: In which browser your website scrolbar appearing ?

Comment: All of them, I have hidden it in firefox using CSS. I want to fix the content so I don't need to use CSS to hide the scroll bar.

Comment: then remove css to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your site on firebug

Seems like

```
    .footer-wrap {margin :0 -8em}
```

is causing it. Cant figure out why you applied it, guess you can either do away with it or work your way around it. Disabling it fixed things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that padding: 0 1em; and width: 96% on body and set right:0px on element with id socialslider

Comment: I just tried that and still no luck, any chance of checking out what else could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

in .footer-wrap (custom.css)

change the margin from

`0 -8em`

to

`0 auto`

this works for me using firebug in chrome.

Comment: Ok what I did was change the margin and padding to 0px in custom.css for Body, Top and Footer-wrap to solve the problem.